# SQL Server returns datetime like 2015-12-07T09:20:17.097

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services

Using ASP.NET API I inserted DateTime using **GetDate()** SQL Server function, as I select back data it gives format like this `2015-12-07T09:20:17.097`, and also the time is not correct to my current time while record inserted.

How can I get/insert my time according to local timezone

Comment: GetDate returns the current date and time from the server hosting SQL Server.  Is the time wrong or for a different time zone?

Comment: I think its from diff time zone here is the saved value **2015-12-07T09:19:23.4**, but here time is not correct to my time zone. how can i insert/retrieve as my Time Zone

Comment: SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() returns the current server time with GMT offset.  You could use this to diff against your local offset.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677334.aspx

Comment: Its just conversion of DateTime to Data/Time
I need to convert to my Time Zone either before insertion or fetching

Comment: I've added an answer below that shows you how to change from one timezone to another.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do that:

> 1. Format data with SQL select query date formatter
>        Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp
> 2. With ASP.net c#/Vb.net, you may use Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("put format here");
>       Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment
Here is my return value how can change it to my time zone, bcz its time is not correct
2015-12-07T09:19:23.4

Comment: Issue isn't with format i think its with **time zone** either i will add my time zone while inserting or getting back, but how ? that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions that can help you here.  First is [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677334.aspx).
This returns the date, time and timezone from the server.  If we combine this with [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) we can return the date and time for another timezone.

Here's an example that returns US Eastern time (-05:00):

```
SELECT
    SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-05:00') AS EasternTime
```

The time zone parameter is daylight saving awear.

This next example demonstrates that the time zone parameter sets the time zone, rather than just adding/subtracting the hours and minutes passed:

```
DECLARE @GMT            DATETIMEOFFSET = '2015-12-17 09:00:00.0000000 +00:00'
DECLARE @GMT_Plus1    DATETIMEOFFSET = '2015-12-17 10:00:00.0000000 +01:00'


/* Both 9am in timezone +0 (London) and 10am in +1 (Paris)
 * will return 4am Eastern time (timezone -5)
 */  
SELECT
    SWITCHOFFSET(@GMT, '-05:00')        AS EasternTime1,
    SWITCHOFFSET(@GMT_Plus1, '-05:00')    AS EasternTime2
;
```

Both these functions require SQL Server 2008 or higher.  For more on SQL Server's date and time functionality see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx).